# xQuery How to sort result in multiple for loops

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

First of all, sorry for the misleading title, I'm having trouble formulating this question.

Using the following XML file, which contains some information about different players, different teams and a relation between those 2 last, called PlayerTeams.

```
<Ligue>
    <Players>
        <Player>
            <PlayerId>1</PlayerId>
            <PlayerName>Johnson</PlayerName>
            <PlayerFirstName>Steven</PlayerFirstName>
        </Player>

        <Player>
            <PlayerId>2</PlayerId>
            <PlayerName>Bob</PlayerName>
            <PlayerFirstName>Billy</PlayerFirstName>
        </Player>

        <Player>
            <PlayerId>3</PlayerId>
            <PlayerName>Smith</PlayerName>
            <PlayerFirstName>John</PlayerFirstName>
        </Player>
    </Players>

    <Teams>
        <Team>
            <TeamId>1</TeamId>
            <TeamName>The super Zubats</TeamName>
        </Team>

        <Team>
            <TeamId>2</TeamId>
            <TeamName>The diglets trio</TeamName>
        </Team>
    </Teams>

    <PlayerTeams>
        <PlayerTeam>
            <PlayerId>1</PlayerId>
            <TeamId>1</TeamId>
            <DateBegin>2013-12-01</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd></DateEnd>
            <Number>69</Number>
        </PlayerTeam>

        <PlayerTeam>
            <PlayerId>1</PlayerId>
            <TeamId>2</TeamId>
            <DateBegin>2013-01-10</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd>2013-11-20</DateEnd>
            <Number>69</Number>
        </PlayerTeam>

        <PlayerTeam>
            <PlayerId>2</PlayerId>
            <TeamId>2</TeamId>
            <DateBegin>2013-01-10</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd></DateEnd>
            <Number>12</Number>
        </PlayerTeam>

        <PlayerTeam>
            <PlayerId>3</PlayerId>
            <TeamId>2</TeamId>
            <DateBegin>2013-01-10</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd></DateEnd>
            <Number>73</Number>
        </PlayerTeam>
    </PlayerTeams>
</Ligue>
```

What I have to do here is to find, with Xquery, each players that play in a team. In the end, I would need to have to listing of a team and every players inside it. Unfortunatly, I'm really new to Xquery and all I managed to do is to list each players with the team he plays in, with the following code

```
for $b in doc("ligue.xml")/Ligue/Teams/Team,
    $c in doc("ligue.xml")/Ligue/PlayerTeams/PlayerTeam,
    $d in doc("ligue.xml")/Ligue/Players/Player
            where $c/TeamId = $b/TeamId and empty($c/DateEnd) and $c/PlayerId = $d/PlayerId
                return <Team>{$b/TeamName,<Player>{string($d/PlayerFirstName), string($d/PlayerName)}</Player>}</Team>
```

Which give me a result like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Team>
    <TeamName>The super Zubats</TeamName>
    <Player>Steven Johnson</Player>
</Team>
```

I was wondering if anyone could give me a hint on how to achieve my goal. I tried to use "let" but I don't seem to understand how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First iterate over teams and then do a join over players and playerTeams:

```
for $team in doc("ligue.xml")/Ligue/Teams/Team
  return 
    <Team>
       {$team/TeamName}
       {for $player in doc("ligue.xml")/Ligue/Players/Player, 
            $playerTeam in doc("ligue.xml")/Ligue/PlayerTeams/PlayerTeam
          where $player/PlayerId = $playerTeam/PlayerId and $playerTeam/TeamId = $team/TeamId
          return $player}
   </Team>
```

I hope this query is self explanatory, but if not add a comment :)

Comment: That worked exactly as intended! Thank you very much for the help